# Unable to clear selection in a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Simple enough requirement - trying to reset a WPF combobox on user press of a "clear" button. Everything else on the form clears as expected, with the exception of this ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" DisplayMemberPath="MemberName" SelectedValue="{Binding RequestingMember, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="MemberID" IsEditable="{Binding FixedRequestingMember }"></ComboBox>
```

Here's the property it's bound to:

```
    public int RequestingMember
    {
        get { return _requestingMember; }
        set
        {
            if (_requestingMember != value)
            {
                _requestingMember = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's what I'm using to clear the box:

```
this.RequestingMember = -1;
```

Worth mentioning that there's nothing in the Members collection which corresponds to a key of -1. The value doesn't change from its selection when you press clear, anyway.

I've tried setting the `int` to 0 and also setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the XAML, to no avail. I'm loathe to change `RequestingMemeber` to a type of `int?` as it'll need fixes that cascade a long way into other parts of the application.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why bind to the index?  Why not just bind to `SelectedItem`?  That way you can null it out when you want to clear it.  Dealing with indexes is more complex and doesn't give you any benefits :/

Comment: The fact that you use "-1" makes me think that you confuse `SelectedValue` with `SelectedIndex`. If the combo box is editable, it can be **any** string, not just the values from the drop down list; i.e. you should bind to `Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for the full information on this, but in short, you will have more luck by data binding to the `SelectedItem` property, rather than using the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` properties. Try adding a property of the same type as the items in the collection and data binding that to the `SelectedItem` property instead:

```
public Member SelectedMember // Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface here!!
{
    get { return selectedMember; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedMember != value)
        {
            selectedMember = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedMember");
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your class with the properties. Your XAML should now look like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" DisplayMemberPath="MemberName" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMember, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsEditable="{Binding FixedRequestingMember }" />
```

Now all you need to do to clear the selection is this:

```
SelectedMember = null;
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't my code originally, and the guy that wrote it left :) The reason it uses the index is because this value is used elsewhere on this form as a FK - i.e. it's recorded in the DB as a numeric. So I'll have to do some refactoring to handle this. FYI - all the base classes already have INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: *all the base classes already have INotifyPropertyChanged*... you didn't show it in your `RequestingMember` property. Either way, you can still use the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` properties as well as the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: No, it's inherited - but my apologies for not making that clear. Thanks for the useful answer.